# check if the file is existing or not

Tags: c++

i want to know what is the error here . i want to enter the name of the file then check if the file is existing or not but my code doesn't work and i don't know why !

```
#include <fstream> //for file I/O
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    string filename;
    cout << "Input a filename:  ";
    cin >> filename;
    fstream filestr;
      filestr.open (filename);
      if (filestr.is_open())
      {
        filestr << "File successfully open";
        filestr.close();
      }
      else
      {
        cout << "Error opening file";
      }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Define "error". Compile time or run-time?

Comment: You should declare the stream type. I mean directions, e.g, in or out. see this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/

Comment: For older standards definitions use `filestr.open (filename.c_str());`

Comment: your code looks fine, maybe its path problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `std::fstream` here when you probably want to use `std::ifstream` to specify that you want to take input and not write output.

```
std::ifstream file(filename);
bool exists = file; // operator bool()
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
  filestr.open (filename);
```

should be

```
  filestr.open (filename.c_str());
```

However, there is overload available in C++11 which takes string as its parameter.

In C++11 :-

```
void open (const char* filename,
           ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
void open (const string& filename,
           ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
```